# Vue with XMLHttpRequest of Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-api

I have a function in my VueJS app which is attempting to load a Google Calendar

```js
loadCalendar() {
    var comp = this;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events');                                   
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer' + comp.access_token, true);
    console.log("comp access token is = " + comp.access_token)
    xhr.send();
   }
```

And I have retrieved an access token, using Google's `client.requestAccessToken` that is stored against `access_token`.

Unfortunately, I am receiving a 401 error of `The request is missing a valid API key.`

I have also tried appending the API key to the URL as:   `'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendar_id}?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]'`

Any advice on how I fix this is much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: there should be a space between 'Bearer' and the access token.  `'Bearer ' + comp.access_token`

Comment: Thanks @yoduh that partly fixed it. Being new to JS I didn't realise that the response would not automatically appear in the console. Once I console.logged it I could see it.